# RSPEC error: expected #<> got #<> (compared using ==) - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, controller, factory-bot

I am testing my controller with RSPEC in ruby on rails. Here is the (relevant parts of the) controller action i am testing,

**Controller Code:**

```
 before do 
    @company=FactoryGirl.create(:company)
    @customer=FactoryGirl.create(:customer, company_id: @company.id)
    @job=FactoryGirl.create(:job, customer_id: @customer.id, company_id:  @company.id)
  end

class JobsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    if params[:customer_id]
      @job = current_member.company.jobs.new(
        customer_id: params[:customer_id],
        lead_id: params[:lead_id]
      )
     else
      ...
     end
    ...
  end
```

**RSPEC Code:**

```
   it "has valid job with customer_id param" do 
      get :new, {:customer_id=>@customer.id, :lead_id=>@job.lead_id}
      expect(assigns(:job)).to eq @member.company.jobs.new(customer_id:@customer.id, lead_id:@job.lead_id)
    end
```

**Here is the error I am getting:**

```
Failures:

   1) Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:job)).to eq @member.company.jobs.new(customer_id:@customer.id, lead_id:@job.lead_id)

   expected: #<Job id: nil, name: nil, status: "pending", company_id: 43, account_id_old: nil, job_type_id: nil, address_id: nil, trade_id: nil, lead_id: nil, started_date: nil, end_date: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, order_number: nil, creator_id: nil, account_id: nil, customer_id: 22, contact_id: nil>
        got: #<Job id: nil, name: nil, status: "pending", company_id: 43, account_id_old: nil, job_type_id: nil, address_id: nil, trade_id: nil, lead_id: nil, started_date: nil, end_date: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, order_number: nil, creator_id: nil, account_id: nil, customer_id: 22, contact_id: nil>

   (compared using ==)
```

I dont get it, both the 'expected' and the 'got' sections appear to be the same thing! Ideas/Help please?

Answer (score 1):

Just because the data is the same, doesn't mean they're the same object (which they're not).

You really need to check the various things about your assigned object individually, eg:

```
before { get :new, { customer_id: @customer.id, lead_id: @job.lead_id } }

subject(:job) { assigns :job }

it { is_expected.to be_a_new Job }

it "should have the right customer_id" do
  expect(job.customer_id).to eq @customer.id
end

it "should have the right lead_id" do
  expect(job.lead_id).to eq @job.lead_id
end
```

...something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Since both objects are not saved, and you don't really want to test if they are exactly the same object, you could check if their attributes match, the comparison will be between two hashes

```
it "has valid job with customer_id param" do 
  get :new, {:customer_id=>@customer.id, :lead_id=>@job.lead_id}
  expect(assigns(:job).attributes).to eq @member.company.jobs.new(customer_id:@customer.id, lead_id:@job.lead_id).attributes
end
```